# How to set version number from Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup

I have a script that reads the version number from an application file. Now I need to find a way to place this number in the `AppVersion` directive of Inno Setup.

How can I place the return value of my function in the `AppVersion` directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

```
[Setup]
AppVersion={code:GetAppVersion}
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetAppVersion(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := MyFunction;
end;
```

If the function call is costly, you should cache its value to a global variable and use the cached value in the scripted constant.